# FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have spent 4 days trying to get **EF Core** to save a datetime value for a record. 
 It keeps failing with the following error:

**FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.**

I have looked at almost a hundred posts regarding something similar to no avail.  I've tried multiple datetime formats.  Below is a link to the latest attempt in Visual Studio with some watches set for pertinent values.

```
    var format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";
    var stringDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
    gl.LastUpdate =DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate,format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    db.SaveChanges(); //Entity Framework Core

        //model snip
        [Display(Name = "Updated Date")]
        public  DateTime? LastUpdate { get; set; }
```

I attempted to find documentation for the datetime format that EF Core is expecting with no success.

I can't save my record because of this error.  I assume it has to be something relatively simple and hope that someone can shed some light on this.

Exception Details

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.FormatException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime. ---> System.FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(Object value, MetaType destinationType, Boolean& coercedToDataFeed, Boolean& typeChanged, Boolean allowStreaming)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.GetCoercedValue()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.Validate(Int32 index, Boolean isCommandProc)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildParamList(TdsParser parser, SqlParameterCollection parameters)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BuildExecuteSql(CommandBehavior behavior, String commandText, SqlParameterCollection parameters, _SqlRPC& rpc)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, String executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean closeConnection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(Tuple`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at TMain.Models.TmainContext.SaveChanges() in C:\Users\dmcquay\Source\Workspaces\SCM\NET Core\TMainModel\Models\tmainContext.cs:line 123
   at TMain.Data.GLConfigurationRepository.SaveChanges() in C:\Users\dmcquay\Source\Workspaces\SCM\NET Core\TMainModel\Data\GLConfigurationRepository.cs:line 40
   at GLCoderConfiguration.Controllers.GLConfigController.Save(Int32 id, String userName) in C:\Users\dmcquay\Source\Workspaces\SCM\NET Core\GLCoderConfiguration\Controllers\GLConfigController.cs:line 181
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.<Invoke>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.<Invoke>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.BrowserLinkMiddleware.<ExecuteWithFilter>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()`

Comment: Post your code in the body of your question, do not link to images or external code sites.

Comment: Please paste the relevant portions of your code into the question. Nobody's going to click through to something off site. Screenshots of code are just an insult. They're not searchable. What good are they? Include an example of the string it can't parse, also.

Comment: the links were StackOverflows they will not let me insert images.

Comment: @dmcquay Paste code as text. Not image. Text. You can paste text.

Comment: and how do i edit this existing post?

Comment: @dmcquay Click "edit"

Comment: there is not edit button for the original post

Comment: @dmcquay Its literally right below your tags.

Comment: Edited.  Did not see it.

Comment: @dmcquay Well golly. Yes, the "{0" stuff parses fine for me too. You're right, the format string is not the source of the error.

Comment: Somewhere internal to EF Core then.  I am relatively new to EF Core but did not expect to have problems as simple as saving a datetime value to the db.  Assumed there was something simple I missed.

Comment: may you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Added exception details.

Comment: Why are you first converting a DateTime value to a string and then immediately try to parse it? Why not just use the DateTime value directly? In other words, why aren't you just doing `gl.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mixing data annotations and fluent api on my model.  I changed to data annotations only and things started working.  Apparently one or more of the fluent api settings was confusing EF Core.

Answer (score 1):

Change the second line.  You can't use format string with `{0:` prefix in the ToString method call:

```
var stringDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: I've tried it both ways and i still get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The reason here is that you're converting your `DateTime` value to a string and then try to parse it back to a DateTime, and you specify a culture for the parsing but not for the formatting.

So either pass a culture to the ToString method, or remove it from the parsing...

**However**, the entire problem can be bypassed entirely by just **not** doing the above juggling between strings and DateTime values.

Simply replace all this code:

```
var format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";
var stringDate = DateTime.Now.ToString(format);
gl.LastUpdate =DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate,format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

With this:

```
gl.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: This is what I did the very first time I wrote the code.  Other issues dealing with data annotations vs fluent api was the problem and will be indicated as solution as soon as i can do it.